# Using environment vars in two libraries Angular 9

Tags: angular, shared-libraries

I built my Angular 9 project the following way:

- APP1
- APP2
- Services Library LIB1
- Components Library LIB2

Both APP1 and APP2 use services and components from both LIB1 and LIB2, and LIB2 uses services from LIB1. So far, so good, however APP1 points to an API endpoint and APP2 points to another API endpoint (same API, just different databases). I've managed to pass the endpoint to LIB1 and LIB2 separately, like so:

```
  export class LIB1ServicesModule { 
  public static forRoot({APIbaseURL}): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LIB1ServicesModule ,
      providers: [
        { provide: HTTPSERVICESETTINGS, useValue: APIbaseURL },
      ]
    };
  }
}

[...]

  export class LIB2ComponentsModule { 
  public static forRoot({APIbaseURL}): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LIB2ComponentsModule ,
      providers: [
        { provide: HTTPSERVICESETTINGS, useValue: APIbaseURL },
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

However, I'm not having much luck when I'm trying to use the **APIbaseURL** to inject the value from LIB2 into the LIB1 Services Module, like below:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { LIB1ServicesModule } from '@myserviceslib';
import { FileUpload } from './file-upload/file-upload.component';
import { HTTPSERVICESETTINGS } from './tokens/tokens';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [FileUpload],
  imports: [
    LIB1ServicesModule.forRoot({APIbaseURL: <<my problem here!!>>})
  ],
  exports: [FileUpload]
})
export class LIB2ComponentsModule { 
  public static forRoot({APIbaseURL}): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LIB2ComponentsModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: HTTPSERVICESETTINGS, useValue: APIbaseURL },
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Just as a FYI, the tokens module is like so:

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const HTTPSERVICE = new InjectionToken('http-service');
export const HTTPSERVICESETTINGS = new InjectionToken('http-service-settings');
```

After all this explanation, my question should be simple (and probably simpler yet to answer, but I'm stuck), how could I use the value I pass as APIbaseURL to LIB2 as the value needed in LIB1 inside LIB2 module?

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: Not at the moment, I'll see if I can provide one later today.

Comment: ok, will wait for it.